# Will disabled secure boot put at risk my pc?

Tags: linux, windows, secure-boot, rootkit, dualboot

I'm having Windows 10 and Linux on dual boot on my PC. I'm using Linux all the time but now I want to play something that runs only on Windows 10.

The secure boot on my PC is disabled.

On Windows I've got only Windows Defender. Is it risky for me to use Windows 10 without any 3rd party antivirus and disabled secure boot (aware from rootkit etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

In and of itself, disabling secure boot won't put your PC at risk BUT if your computer IS compromised it is possible for an attacker to compromise your system more thoroughly and to hide their tracksmuch  better and in ways that are harder to remove.

The risk really depends on how you use your computer, and the value of your data. I'd say that if you are using ad blockers and not doing anything too serious and can spot phishing attacks a mile off and take regular backups the risk is probably acceptable - but no guarantees.

I'd be looking at the problem slightly differently - from the POV of "if bit defender fails, how painful would a full is reinstall be to me? Because really, that's the risk - if Bit defender fails you may not be able to trust your Microsoft install.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your anwser. I already have Win10 installed on my device. Could you please resume your advice? Should i simply install bit defender? is trial enough? Thanks in advance.
EDIT: Or is windows defender enough?

Answer (score 1):

The secure boot won't prevent rootkits to get into the system.
Secure Boot just assures the System you try to boot is trusted. It has nearly nothing to do with Antivirus.
IMHO: No, Windows defender is NOT enough. Most thirdparty AVs are faster and more updated.

Answer (score 0):

Secure boot protects again bootkits and evil maid attacks.

Bootkits are programs that replace programs and files used very early in the boot process. They can be installed onto systems remotely by running a malicious script or executable.

Evil maid attacks are when a person physically has access to your computer and replaces these files by hand.

Both are very hard to detect without the firmware validating what is being executed during the boot process.

Bootkits can be a concern to anybody, but are not that common and mostly are relevant to persistence, because usually the attacker already needs privileged access and for most people their data is already compromised at that point.

Evil maid attacks would mostly be a concern to high profile targets, like government officials or whistleblowers and datacenters.

As a general rule of thumb, if you run signed software, inspect the scripts that you run, validate your downloads, use HTTPS, update your software from trusted sources and use common sense, not even an antivirus is needed, especially on Linux. At the time of this answer's writing Windows 10's or 11's Windows Defender is actually pretty good if it is connected to Microsoft's network, so no, I do not think that extra AVs are needed.

Secure boot is about validating the executables of the early boot process, but it is important to note that at least the time of this answer, only Ubuntu 23.10 offers the option out of the box as an experiment to make sure that the initramfs on a Linux system is to be trusted by bundling it into a UKI (like basically Windows does), signing that and launching that. Of course on advanced distros you can do so manually and automate that, which has the added benefit for better customization.

It is important to note that secure boot is only as useful as the system above that, meaning if core system files are replaced with something malicious, it will not help. On Linux becuase of Android this can be validated in a similar matter to secure boot via fs-verity, but for desktop use cases this is not widespread, only tinkerers do it right now. Windows might have some feature like this, but I am not well-versed in that.

For a general overview I suggest reading [the Arch Wiki on secure boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot),[Microsoft's security docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/) and [about verity](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-verity).